Configuring Routed Static IP Addresses from ISP on Linux Router
I have received 4 static IP addresses from my ISP on a business plan which are to be used on a Linux-powered router and configured via the ip command. My previous ISP gave me 4 /32 IP addresses which simply required being added to the WAN interface and would work independent of each other; however, my new ISP has given me a "routed" /30 block of 4 IP addresses.
I have been unable to figure out how to add these IP addresses as I receive either error: nexthop has invalid gateway or the IP addresses are added but fail to resolve any external IP addresses or destination hosts.
My new ISP's network configuration is as follows:

WAN: 1.1.1.2/30
Gateway: 1.1.1.1/30
Routed: 1.1.1.4/30

My ISP claims that the gateway address may not be required, and to use the WAN address as the upstream. My router has 2 NICs; 1 for LAN, and 1 for WAN. I am also using iptables to configure the firewall.
How is this setup correctly configured on a Linux system via the ip command?

Please, never use someone else's IP addressing for examples. IANA has put aside three IPv4 ranges (192.31.196.0/24. 198.51.100.0/24. and 203.0.113.0/24), and one IPv6 range (2001:db8::/32) for such example addresses. You would not want someone to use your public addresses for such an example, else you would just use your own public addresses for your example. An IPv4 /30 network has two usable IPv4 addresses, and your example routed address is outside the network of the other two addresses that are in the same /30 network.

@RonMaupin While I'm not against using the proper example IP addresses, how can I show that they are all on the same subnet when mine are not? Also, does this mean I have only 2 usable IP addresses? I've never dealt with any CIDR outside of /8, /16, /24, and /32, so I am confused as to how my ISP's setup works. They said they have their business customers on a VLAN, which is why they use /30 rather than /32.

/30 gives you four total addresses, but remember that you cannot use the network or broadcast addresses in the network, meaning there are two usable addresses in a /30 network, e.g. /30 would give you .0, .1, .2, and .3 in the network, but .0 is an unusable network address, and .3 is an unusable broadcast address. /29 gives you eight total addresses, and six usable addresses, and /28 give you 16 total addresses with 14 usable addresses.

This two-part answer explains all about IPv4 addressing and subnetting.

Here is the previous answer a bit refined, it should work:
# Configure WAN interface
sudo ip addr add 1.1.1.2/30 dev eth0
sudo ip link set eth0 up

# Optionally add routed IP addresses
sudo ip addr add 1.1.1.4/32 dev eth0
sudo ip addr add 1.1.1.5/32 dev eth0
sudo ip addr add 1.1.1.6/32 dev eth0
sudo ip addr add 1.1.1.7/32 dev eth0

# Enable IP forwarding
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

# SNAT rules
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.1.0.2/32 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to 1.1.1.4
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.1.0.3/32 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to 1.1.1.5
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.1.0.4/32 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to 1.1.1.6
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.1.0.5/32 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to 1.1.1.7

# DNAT rules
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 1.1.1.4 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.0.2
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 1.1.1.5 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.0.3
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 1.1.1.6 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.0.4
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 1.1.1.7 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.0.5

# Forwarding rules
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -d 10.1.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT

# Save iptables configuration (adjust based on your distribution)
sudo sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4"

I hope it helps, it should work.

To configure your Linux router with the provided network information, you'll need to set up the WAN interface with the given /30 addresses and then route the /30 routed block through it.
1: Configure the WAN Interface
sudo ip addr add 1.1.1.2/30 dev eth0
sudo ip link set eth0 up

Replace eth0 with the actual name of your WAN interface.
Add the default route:
Since your ISP mentioned that the gateway might not be required and the WAN address should be used as the upstream, let's set up the default route using the gateway provided:
sudo ip route add default via 1.1.1.1 dev eth0

2: Configure the Routed Block
Add the routed /30 block to the WAN interface:
You need to ensure that these addresses are available for use. This involves adding them to a dummy interface or simply ensuring they're routed correctly. Here, we'll add them directly to the WAN interface for simplicity:
sudo ip addr add 1.1.1.4/30 dev eth0

Set up the routing for the routed block:
If you need to route the traffic from these IP addresses through your WAN interface, you will need to ensure that they are routed correctly. Assuming eth1 is your LAN interface:
sudo ip route add 1.1.1.4/30 dev eth1

3: IP Forwarding and Firewall Configuration
Enable IP forwarding:
To allow the router to forward packets between interfaces, enable IP forwarding:
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

To make this change permanent, add or modify the following line in /etc/sysctl.conf:
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

Configure iptables for NAT and Forwarding:
You need to set up iptables to handle NAT (Network Address Translation) if you're planning to share the routed IP block with devices on your LAN:
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state   ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

Verify your IP address and routing configuration:
ip addr show
ip route show

Ping an external IP address to ensure that your routing is working correctly:
ping 8.8.8.8

Save Your Configuration:
Make sure to save your IP and routing configurations using your network manager or by creating appropriate scripts to run at startup.
In short, here is a summary of what we've done:
# Set up WAN interface
sudo ip addr add 1.1.1.2/30 dev eth0
sudo ip link set eth0 up
sudo ip route add default via 1.1.1.1 dev eth0

# Add routed block
sudo ip addr add 1.1.1.4/30 dev eth0
sudo ip route add 1.1.1.4/30 dev eth1

# Enable IP forwarding
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

# Configure iptables for NAT and forwarding
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

This setup should enable your Linux router to properly handle the given static IP addresses and route traffic appropriately.

After doing everything here in the order specified, my network does indeed work, but only on the router. What would the procedure be to properly NAT my 10.1.0.0/24 LAN through the WAN interface?

For example, I need each of the 4 public IP addresses to NAT to a different LAN IP address. Also, does the /30 have to be included in the IP addresses in iptables commands, or can /32 be used since they are for single hosts each?
